# R data.table conditional sum by row

Tags: r, sum, data.table, conditional-statements, row

```
> tempDT <- data.table(colA = c("E","E","A","C","E","C","E","C","E"), colB = c(20,30,40,30,30,40,30,20,10), group = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), want = c(NA, 30, 40, 70,NA,40,70,20,30))
> tempDT
   colA colB group want
1:    E   20     1   NA
2:    E   30     1   30
3:    A   40     1   40
4:    C   30     1   70
5:    E   30     2   NA
6:    C   40     2   40
7:    E   30     2   70
8:    C   20     2   20
9:    E   10     2   30
```

I have columns 'colA' 'colB' 'group': within each 'group', I would like to sum up 'colB' from bottom up until 'colA' is 'E'.

Comment: Your condition is not clear based on the 'want'  What if there are more 'E's for each group after some other character

Comment: And please `dput()` your data ;-)

Comment: @akrun The sample data have been changed. Look forward to your approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the expected 'want', we create a run-length-id column 'grp' by checking if the value is 'E' in 'colA', then create 'want1' as the cumulative sum of 'colB' after grouping by 'grp' and 'group', get the row index ('i1') of elements that are `duplicated` in 'colA' and also is 'E' and assign the  'colB' values to 'want1'

```
tempDT[, grp:= rleid(colA=="E") * (colA != "E")
        ][grp!= 0, want1 := cumsum(colB), .(grp, group)]
i1 <- tempDT[, .I[colA=="E" & duplicated(colA)], group]$V1
tempDT[i1, want1 := colB][, grp := NULL][]
#    colA colB group want want1
#1:    E   20     1   NA    NA
#2:    E   30     1   30    30
#3:    A   40     1   40    40
#4:    C   30     1   70    70
#5:    E   30     2   NA    NA
#6:    C   30     2   30    30
```

Comment: the sample dataset have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(row_num = n():1) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(sum_colB = sum(colB[row_num < row_num[which(colA=='E')]]),
         flag = ifelse(row_num >= row_num[which(colA=='E')], 0, 1),) %>%
  mutate(sum_colB = ifelse(flag==1 & row_num==1, sum_colB, ifelse(flag==0, NA, colB))) %>%
  select(-flag, -row_num) %>%
  data.frame()
```

**Output is:**

```
  colA colB group want sum_colB
1    E   20     1   NA       NA
2    E   30     1   30       NA
3    A   40     1   40       40
4    C   30     1   70       70
5    E   30     2   NA       NA
6    C   30     2   30       30
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(colA = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"C", "E"), class = "factor"), colB = c(20, 30, 40, 30, 30, 30
), group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), want = c(NA, 30, 40, 70, NA, 
30)), .Names = c("colA", "colB", "group", "want"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks @Prem. Is there a way to make your output exactly the same structure as the dataset 'tempDT' above?

Comment: Pls refer the updated answer. (BTW I am not sure on what logic `want` column in second row has `30` but fifth row has `NA`. Also the logic in your updated sample data is not clear to me on how would you like to have `want` column in the output)

Answer (score 0):

There's one approach: row reference + sums

```
# input data
tempDT <- data.table(colA = c("E","E","A","C","E","C","E","C","E"), colB = c(20,30,40,30,30,40,30,20,10), group = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), want = c(NA, 30, 40, 70,NA,40,70,20,30))
tempDT

# find row reference previous row where colA is "E"
lastEpos <- function(i) tail(which(tempDT$colA[1:(i-1)] == "E"), 1)
tempDT[, rowRef := sapply(.I, lastEpos), by = "group"]

# sum up
sumEpos <- function(i) {
  valTEMP <- tempDT$rowRef[i]
  outputTEMP <- sum(tempDT$colB[(valTEMP+1):i])  # sum
  return(outputTEMP)
}
tempDT[, want1 := sapply(.I, sumEpos), by = "group"]

# deal with first row in every group
tempDT[, want1 := c(NA, want1[-1]), by = "group"]

# clean output
tempDT[, rowRef := NULL]
tempDT
```